# Salesforce Bulk upload Error using Apex Data loader: Storage limited exceeded

Tags: salesforce, bulkinsert, bulkloader, bulk-load

When i try to bulk upload 25,000 records of a custom (employee) object i get errors stating "storage limits exceeded".
I have ensured that there are no employee objects in salesforce (using data loader delete). I ensured that recycle bin has been emptied. My batch size is 100 while using the data loader

Now, when i try the same operation using a java client and bulk upload API, the upload works perfectly, with no errors even at 100,000 records insert

Does anyone know why i get this error only while using the apex data loader?

Comment: What does your storage usage look like after you've uploaded 100k records using the Java client? Sounds to me like you're probably going over your limit (which is possible) and dataloader has better error checking going on. Is this a sandbox, developer edition or what?

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem. I was going over the limit in both cases (using bulk API and dataloader). I think i got lucky with the bulk API. I could not repeat inserting even 25k records yesterday, using bulk API. Both approaches failed at differing percentages of exceeding the free 5MB mark. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, I knew I should have tried to phrase that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that other sobjects, documents and attachments are eating up the space. It will help if you can check how much space is available to you in total and how much is left. To do so, please goto Setup > Administration Setup > Data Management > Storage usage.
This screen will give you high level and fine details of which object has how many records and consuming how many bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I was going over the storage limit in both cases (using bulk API and dataloader). I think i got lucky with the bulk API. I could not repeat inserting even 25k records yesterday, using bulk API. Both approaches failed at differing percentages of exceeding the free 5MB mark.
The confusion arises because the "storage exceeded error" does not appear immediately after storage is exceeded. It could appear after 15MB is used or 100 MB (over the default free of 5MB).

Conclusion: The storage exceeded error will appear irrespective of using bulk api or apex data loader for inserts once the data storage allocated for that user account is exceeded. One needs to buy more storage!
Thanks
Sameer